# Retrofit2 response code=401, message=Unauthorized. How to solve?

Tags: java, spring, rest, retrofit2, okhttp

I use Retrofit2 to make REST API requests. I have my dummy server (that runs with spring boot) on my machine:

```
@RestController
class SecureServiceController {
    private int counter = 1;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/nnrf-nfm/v1/nf-instances/bee75393-2ac3-4e60-9503-854e733309d4", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<NFProfile> nNrfNfManagementNfRegister() {

        System.out.println(counter++ + ". Got NrfClient register request. " + new Date());
        NFProfile nfProfile = new NFProfile();
        nfProfile.setHeartBeatTimer(2);
        ResponseEntity<NFProfile> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(201).body(nfProfile);
        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

When client make request from the same machine it works. But when client make request from remote machine I have error response:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=https://myhostname:8443/nnrf-nfm/v1/nf-instances/bee75393-2ac3-4e60-9503-854e733309d4} 
Response error body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>Error</title></head><body><h1>Error</h1></body></html>
```

I've read that such error means that client don't have the rights to access and need to add access token. But my server does not ask any access token (at least explicitly) and it should not ask it.
How to solve this problem?

My apiClient:

```
public class ApiClient {
    private Map<String, Interceptor> apiAuthorizations;
    private Builder okBuilder;
    private retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder adapterBuilder;
    private JSON json;

    //a lot setters and getters

    public <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return this.adapterBuilder.client(this.okBuilder.build()).build().create(serviceClass);
    }

    public void configureFromOkclient(OkHttpClient okClient) {
        this.okBuilder = okClient.newBuilder();
        this.addAuthsToOkBuilder(this.okBuilder);
    }
}
```

my interface:

```
public interface NfInstanceIdDocumentApi {
    @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json"})
    @PUT("nf-instances/{nfInstanceID}")
    Call<NFProfile> registerNFInstance(@Body NFProfile body, @Path("nfInstanceID") UUID nfInstanceID, @Header("Content-Encoding") String contentEncoding, @Header("Accept-Encoding") String acceptEncoding);
}
```

How I do call:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient= ClientFactory.createClient();
ApiClient client = new ApiClient();
client.configureFromOkclient(okHttpClient);
NFProfile body = getNfProfile();
String baseUri = getBaseUri();
UUID uuid = getUUID();

//create call
client.getAdapterBuilder().baseUrl(baseUri);
NfInstanceIdDocumentApi service = client.createService(NfInstanceIdDocumentApi.class);
Call<NFProfile> call = service.registerNFInstance(body, uuid, null, null);

//make call
Response<NFProfile> response = call.execute();
```

**UPD**

I found the problem. Server was running on Windows machine and firewall blocked incoming requests.

Comment: Have an existing WebSecurityConfiguration?

Comment: @pirho, thanks for suggestion. This was the first thing that I thought about. But right now I found that server is running on my Windows machine. And firewall blocked the requests.